# Google Apps Script w/ Google sheet - For each function to manipulate a query, then send an email including a page of results

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jh8uZi3TrBr3ZGe5iPCeGcUdZyiW96ScmnztHr8g-oo/edit?usp=sharing

This might be a bit long to ask anyone to solve the whole thing, but if you guys could tell me the names of what I'm trying to do or point me in the direction of resources, I'd really appreciate it! I'm still very new to Apps Script (and Java Script).

On the "List Operator" tab there's a pivot table made from the "Sample Data". For each name on that list I want the function to:

Copy the name, then paste it to A1 on the "Email Query Funtion" tab. That will update the query on that page and also populate the corresponding email address in B1.

Then I'd like to send that query result in an email to the corresponding email address in B2. Subject has a %NAME% item I'd like to replace with that name copied in the first part, but that's not super important. Ideally the message in "Msg" would be on top on the query results in the email.

Script I've tried: (I'm sure it's pretty bad)

````
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

var listsheet = ss.getSheetByName("List Operator");

var querysheet = ss.getSheetByName("Email Query Function");

var msgsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Msg");

var rows = listsheet.getLastRow();

var names = listsheet.getRange(2, 1, rows-2);

var subject = msgsheet.getRange(2, 1);

var bodypart = msgsheet.getRange(2, 2);

var body = bodypart + "\n" + querysheet;

for (i in names){

var row = names[i];

var name = row[0];

querysheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(name);

var emailaddress = querysheet.getRange(1,2);

var lastqueryrow = querysheet.getLastRow();

var report = querysheet.getRange(1 ,1,lastqueryrow,5);

var subjectpart = msgsheet.getRange(2, 1);

var subject = i + subjectpart;

var subject = subject.replace("%NAME%",name);

var bodypart = msgsheet.getRange(2, 2);

var body = bodypart + "\n" + report;

MailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress,subject,body);```
````

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you @Cooper! That really helps a lot! I messed with it a little and got this to work. The only problem is it returns a paragraph of text

```
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var listsheet=ss.getSheetByName("List Operator");
  var querysheet=ss.getSheetByName("Email Query Function");
  var msgsheet=ss.getSheetByName("Msg");
  var names=listsheet.getRange(2,1,listsheet.getLastRow()-2).getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    var row=names[i];
    var name=row[0];
    querysheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(name);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var emailaddress=querysheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
    var lastqueryrow=querysheet.getLastRow();
    var report=querysheet.getRange(1 ,1,querysheet.getLastRow(),5).getValues();
    msgsheet.getRange(3, 2,querysheet.getLastRow(),5).setValues(report);
    var subject=msgsheet.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
    var body=msgsheet.getRange(2, 2,querysheet.getLastRow(),5).getValues();
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress,subject,body);
    msgsheet.getRange(3, 2,querysheet.getLastRow(),5).setValue('');
  }
}
```

returns in the body:
Here's your payout report for this week.

Let me know if you have any questions.,,,,,Diane
Gonzalez,test1@atlantickeyenergy.com,,,,Customer Name,Sale
Date,Sales_ID,Kw,Standard Payout,Henry Day,Tue May 12 2020 00:00:00
GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),Diane Gonzalez,11.7,585,Timothy
Gonzales,Tue May 26 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),Diane
Gonzalez,11.1,555,Deborah Gilbert,Thu Jun 11 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400
(Eastern Daylight Time),Diane Gonzalez,8.4,2805.71,Emily Matthews,Sat Jun
13 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),Diane
Gonzalez,9.6,3623.75,Jimmy Warren,Thu Jun 11 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400
(Eastern Daylight Time),Diane Gonzalez,10.2,

Any ideas to fix it to produce a table?

Comment: That's not going to  work.  report is a two dimensional array.

Comment: Oh so you want to be a table.  Perhaps you should using the htmlBody option.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to work.  See comments and fix.

````
function myfunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var listsheet=ss.getSheetByName("List Operator");
  var querysheet=ss.getSheetByName("Email Query Function");
  var msgsheet=ss.getSheetByName("Msg");
  var names=listsheet.getRange(2,1,listsheet.getLastRow()-1).getValues();
  var subject=msgsheet.getRange(2,1).getValue();//this cant be right it is part of names
  var bodypart=msgsheet.getRange(2,2).getValue();//this cant be right is is part of names
  var body=bodypart + "\n" + querysheet;
  for (let i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    var row=names[i];
    var name=row[0];
    querysheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(name);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var emailaddress=querysheet.getRange(1,2);
    var lastqueryrow=querysheet.getLastRow();
    var report=querysheet.getRange(1 ,1,querysheet.getLastRow(),5).getValues();//two dimensional array
    var subjectpart=msgsheet.getRange(2, 1);
    var subject=i + subjectpart;
    var subject=subject.replace("%NAME%",name);
    var bodypart=msgsheet.getRange(2, 2);
    var body=bodypart + "\n" + report;//this is not a string it's a two dimensional array
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress,subject,body);```
  }
}
````

You can do it this way:

```
let body=msgsheet.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow(),5).getValues().reduce(function(a,r,i){
    a.html+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',r[0],r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4]);
    return a;
  },{html:'<style>td{border:1px solid black;}</style><table>',getHtml: function(){return this.html+'</table>';}}).getHtml();
```